# while_loop in tensorflow returns type error

Tags: tensorflow

I am confused why the following code returns this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/TestPython/tftest.py", line 46, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/Desktop/TestPython/tftest.py", line 35, in main
    result = tf.while_loop(Cond_f2, Body_f1, loop_vars=loopvars)
  File "/Users/Desktop/HPC_LIB/TENSORFLOW/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2518, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/Users/Desktop/HPC_LIB/TENSORFLOW/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2356, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/Users/Desktop/HPC_LIB/TENSORFLOW/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2292, in _BuildLoop
    c = ops.convert_to_tensor(pred(*packed_vars))
  File "/Users/Desktop/TestPython/tftest.py", line 18, in Cond_f2
    boln = tf.less(tf.cast(tf.constant(ind), dtype=tf.int32), tf.cast(tf.constant(N), dtype=tf.int32))
  File "/Users/Desktop/HPC_LIB/TENSORFLOW/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 163, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape))
  File "/Users/Desktop/HPC_LIB/TENSORFLOW/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 353, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/Users/Desktop/HPC_LIB/TENSORFLOW/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 287, in _AssertCompatible
    raise TypeError("List of Tensors when single Tensor expected")
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me fix this error. Thanks!

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import sys
import tensorflow as tf

def Body_f1(n, ind, N, T):
    # Compute trace
    a = tf.trace(tf.random_normal(0.0, 1.0, (n, n)))
    # Update trace
    a = tf.cast(a, dtype=T.dtype)
    T = tf.scatter_update(T, ind, a)
    # Update index
    ind = ind + 1

    return n, ind, N, T

def Cond_f2(n, ind, N, T):
    boln = tf.less(tf.cast(tf.constant(ind), dtype=tf.int32), tf.cast(tf.constant(N), dtype=tf.int32))
    return boln



def main(argv):
    # Open tensorflow session
    sess = tf.Session()

    # Parameters
    N = 10
    T = tf.zeros((N), dtype=tf.float64)
    n = 4
    ind = 0

    # While loop
    loopvars = [n, ind, N, T]
    result = tf.while_loop(Cond_f2, Body_f1, loop_vars=loopvars, shape_invariants=None, \
     parallel_iterations=1, back_prop=False, swap_memory=False, name=None)
    trace = result[3]
    trace = sess.run(trace)
    print trace
    print 'Done!'

    # Close tensorflow session
    if session==None:
        sess.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Update: I have added the full error message. I am not sure why I get this error message.  Does loop_vars expect a single tensor and not a list of tensors? I hope not.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: I have updated my post with a full error message. Many thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

tf.constant expects a non-Tensor value, like a Python list or a numpy array. You can get the same error by iterating tf.constant, as in tf.constant(tf.constant(5.)). Removing those calls fixes that first error. It's a very poor error message, so I would encourage you to [file a bug on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new).

It also looks like the arguments to random_normal are a bit mixed up; keyword arguments are good for avoiding issues like that:

```
tf.random_normal(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, shape=(n, n))
```

Finally scatter_update expects a variable. It looks like a [TensorArray](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/tensor_array_ops.html#TensorArray) may be what you're looking for here (or one of the [higher level looping constructs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html) which use a TensorArray implicitly).